# Related List on OpportunityLineItem

Tags: opportunity, sales-cloud, opportunity-lineitem, quote

I'm looking at something using QuoteLineItems and OpportunityLineItems.  The quoting/selling application is only interested in seeing high level "summary" products; however, there is a need to be able to associate lower level detail components that are priced differently.  For example, there might be a Honda Accord (automobile) summary product that is made up of many individual component pieces, each priced differently and that Honda Accord would just be one of many possible summary products on the Opportunity.

I looked into having a related list on the QuoteLineItem to represent the components. This is able to be done. No problem.  Then I looked at being able to have a related list on the OpportunityLineItem (i.e., custom object with lookup to OpportunityLineItem).  It looks like this is not possible.  Am I missing something?  I see that there is a standard Schedule related list on OpportunityLineItem.  Am I reduced to storing the ID in a text field and using workflow and/or Apex to keep it in sync or is there some other pattern?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. I don't get this one :(!

Comment: @Peter Knolle:Any workaround on related list of opportunitylineitem .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're going to have to store the ID as text.  Currently lookups to OpportunityLineItem's aren't supported :(

I've done this before using Apex to manage the lookups and it's worked just fine.

Comment: Ideas: [Allow lookup relationship to OpportunityLineItem](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000b5OAAAY) is worth promoting.